# How to add a border for carousel with JPEG / PNG image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I would like to view carousel display inside a tablet or mobile or some other picture border I have. Is there a way to place it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understood your problem, then you want to run a bootstrap carousel inside an image wrapper like tablet. For this, you can give a `background-image` to the wrapper div and put the carousel code inside this.

You can see the example which I have created in the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/xxjrk3Lq/1/

Basically, you can use something like following,
in HTML,

```
<div class="bg-image">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/tree_beach_side-wide.jpg" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            First slide label
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://www.freedomwallpaper.com/nature-wallpaper/nature-hd-wallpapers-water.jpg" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            Second slide label
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

In CSS,

```
.bg-image{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background-image:url('http://pngimg.com/upload/tablet_PNG8592.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    padding: 29px 32px;
}
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img, 
.carousel-inner>.item>img{
     height: 222px;   
}
```

and initialize carousel in javascript,

```
$('.carousel').carousel();
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the carousel images perfectly fit inside image wrapper?

Comment: i have added the code in JSFiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/manusekhars/tnfyu9sa/ could you please guide how can it be made to fit perfectly in the image wrapper